# Getting information about highlighted ads in Chrome Devtools / Puppeteer

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

In Puppeteer you can highlight ads on the page with:

```
const devtoolsProtocolClient = await page.target().createCDPSession();
await devtoolsProtocolClient.send('Overlay.setShowAdHighlights', { show: true });
```

Is there a way to get information on each ad afterwards? Looping through the hightlighted areas?

Another option was to search the DOM for the highlight but I can't really see any modifications in those areas.

Comment: I think we don't have an API for that

Comment: Chrome has it, can we try it? :D https://vanilla.aslushnikov.com/?Overlay.setShowAdHighlights

Comment: @hardkoded - I've added a sub question on whether you can access the highlighted areas in an alternative way (via DOM). Perhaps you know anything about that?